# JQuery - Create input with attributes from JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create an input with the id and value attributes set from a JSON. I have an ajax call which gets the JSON and the data returned is just fine, and for each object from the JSON I want to create a button with an ID and a value from the JSON.

The Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSubjects", "CommAPI")',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                    $('#subjects').append('<input type ="button" id=" ' + element.Id + ' " value=' + element.Title + '  class=k-button  />');
                });
            },

        });
```

The objects from the JSON however have 5 additional properties in them, not just Id and Title. When placing the debugger at the line with the input creation, the Id and Title are undefined.

How may I create these inputs from this JSON?

Returned JSON copied from the Console:

```
14:41:57.928 {"Data":[{"Id":1,"IdCSite":1,"IdDEvent":1,"Title":"Test","CaseName":null,"Description":"dsadasdasda","InsertedDate":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","SelectedUsers":null,"ViewSelectedUsers":null,"IsCurrentUserIncluded":false},{"Id":2,"IdCSite":1,"IdDEvent":1,"Title":"Test2","CaseName":null,"Description":"sdadasdas","InsertedDate":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","SelectedUsers":null,"ViewSelectedUsers":null,"IsCurrentUserIncluded":false},{"Id":3,"IdCSite":1,"IdDEvent":1,"Title":"test 3","CaseName":null,"Description":"sdadasdasda","InsertedDate":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","SelectedUsers":null,"ViewSelectedUsers":null,"IsCurrentUserIncluded":false}],"Total":3,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}1 messageboard:128:25
```

Comment: Can you post your JSON?

Comment: try console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) after success. and give data what are you getting

Comment: JSON posted and copied from the Console guys

Comment: `$.each(data.Data,` update to this and it does not have any key named `Id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your JSON, you need to use `Data` property of `data` object. thus change `$.each(data,` to `$.each(data.Data,`

```
 $.each(data.Data, function (index, element) {
     $('#subjects').append('<input type ="button" id="' + element.Id + '"  value="' + element.Title + '"  class=k-button  />');
 });
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Satpal!

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly jQuery properties to make that :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '@Url.Action("GetSubjects", "CommAPI")',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, element) {
      $input = $('<input'>).prop('id', element.Id).prop('title', element.title).addClass('k'); 
      $('#subjects').append($input);
    });
});
```

Becareful how do you name your variable, for example 'Id' is a key word of Javascript. You should name like idu if it's a user for example.

Enjoy :)